# How to regexp a Kibana filter?

Tags: regex, kibana

I want to filter my Kibana logs. In these there is the field **stacktrace** with lots of stacktraces. I want to don't show some stacktrace types.

For this I add a **Filter out value** filter of stacktrace with following value:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "stacktrace": "+ConnectException+"
    }
  }
}
```

Its documented right here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

This does not work, all **ConnectException**s in this case are found, like:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

Comment: I think you need `@&~(.*ConnectException)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is - `+` is a metacharacter in regular expressions (so are `.` characters), and so it won't match when you're assuming.

What you need in your filter is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "stacktrace": "java\.net\.ConnectException.*"
    }
  }
}
```

(and then set it as an exclude)